# How to get a function name passed in parameters?

Tags: c++, arguments

I've just found something as get the name of current function or get name of the caller, some variants to get or call the name as string.

What I want is to get the name of the function that I passed in arguments. Like this:

```
void Bar()
{
//do something
}

void Foo(void (*f)())
{
//this will output: Foo
std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

//How do I get the name passed to f? (in this case: Bar)
}

int main()
{
Foo(Bar);
return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Edit: Here is an extremely near code for what I'm trying following the suggestion of @Jose.

```
    thread_local const char * m_last_function_called = "";
    #define register_function() {m_last_function_called = __FUNCTION__;}
    inline const char * get_last_function() { return m_last_function_called; }

//  const char * g_last_function_called = "";
//  #define register_function() { g_last_function_called = __FUNCTION__; }
//  inline const char * get_last_function() { return g_last_function_called; }

    void print_last_func()
    {
        static std::mutex sync_cout;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(sync_cout);
        std::cout << get_last_function() << std::endl;
    }

    bool interruptFooTimer = false;
    int FooTimer()
    {
        register_function();
        print_last_func();

        std::cout << "FooTimer.start" << std::endl;
        int t = 0;
        while(t<10)
        {
            if(interruptFooTimer==false)
            {
                sleep(1);
                t++;
                std::cout << "\tt=" << t << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "FooTimer.end" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    void CallTrd(int (*f)())
    {
        std::thread TrdTemp(f);
        TrdTemp.detach();
        TrdTemp.~thread();
        print_last_func();
    }

int main()
{
    CallTrd(FooTimer);
    print_last_func();
    int c = 0;
    while(c<15)
    {
        if(c==7) {interruptFooTimer=true;}
        sleep(1);
        c++;
        std::cout << "c=" << c << std::endl;
        print_last_func();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Observe that I call print_last_func() in different moments and all get the same value that was initialized in the variable. This sample code calls a thread without using join() because I can't wait for the thread to finish and also implement the detach() and ~thread to finish my program without any exception. The interruptFooTimer I'm using to safely "terminate" my thread.
What am I missing to get global the value acquired in register_function??

Comment: Pass the name as a separate argument?

Comment: @Mohamad You say maybe something like:
void Foo(void (*f)(),std::string Fname)
and
int main() {Foo(Bar,"Bar");}

Comment: Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. `__FUNCTION__` is expanded by compiler during the compilation time. You cannot get this information in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper macro:

```
#define Foo(x) FooHelper(#x, x)
void FooHelper(const char *f_name, void (*f)())
{
    cout << f_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you wanna do it, but I hope it's for debugging purpose. Obviously the easiest path is to pass the `__FUNCTION__`  as an argument as pointed out. But in my point of view, there's a better approach.

You could have for example, a global variable:

```
thread_local const char * g_last_function_called = ""; 

#define register_function() { g_last_function_called = __FUNCTION__; }
inline const char * get_last_function() { return g_last_function_called; }

void Bar()
{
    register_function() 
}

void Foo(void (*f)())
{
    std::cout << get_last_function() << std::endl;
}

void my_func_that_doesnt_accept_nulls(CClass * p) 
{
     if (p == nullptr)
     {
        std::cout << " function" << get_last_function();
        std::cout << "passed a bad pointer, fix it" << std::endl;
        return;
     }
}
```

Of course, this will not give you the right result in multi-thread, but you can probably fix that using a `thread_local const char * g_last_function_called = ""` variable.

The reason why I like this method is because all you have to do to remove it from your project is just a simple "find and replace" of register_function(), and since it uses plain pointers, there's no way it can slow your program at all.

Edit: this is how I'm testing the code

```
void print_last_func()
{
    static std::mutex sync_cout;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(sync_cout);
    std::cout << get_last_function() << std::endl;
}

void HelloWorld1()
{
    register_function();
    print_last_func();
}

void HelloWorld2()
{
    register_function();
    print_last_func();
}

int main()
{
    register_function();
    std::thread t1(HelloWorld1);
    std::thread t2(HelloWorld2);
    print_last_func();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I get: HelloWorld1, HelloWorld2, and main

Comment: Thanks. It works great with simple functions, but actually you were right about the possibility of multi-thread. The same code but using the thread_local and changing g_last_function_called for m_last_function_called, the register_function() doesn't "update the value" of m_last_function_called variable. Also I had to change all for const char*, my compiler was indicating invalid conversion from char * to const char *.

Comment: I am making some tests here. The register_function() is called correctly and also update the value of m_last_function_called correctly. I put a cout inside register_function and shows the correct name. But, in get_last_function() it returns the original initialized value of m_last_function_called. Something I missed out? The value of thread_local are being destroyed together with the thread? The get_last_function() are not getting the correct scope of the variable?

Comment: @Amperage I made a typo. either use g_variable_name or m_variable_name in all the places. Don't mix them (I edited my reply and you got the second version). I just tested the code creating multiple threads and it works (I had not tested the code before).

Comment: I will ask you a huge favor to take a look in the code that I inserted in the edition of the question. What am I missing? Thank you so much.

Comment: print_last_func() inside CallTrd is supposed to print main, but it doesn't because you didn't use register_function before you called calltrd() on main. Unless that's not what you wanna do, and you want to print what you registered in FooTimer, which is not possible with thread_local bcz what u registered in footimer (thread id 5 for example) will register the name in thrad_local_6_var and inside calltrd you are trying to retrieve the function name from thread_local_5_var which are different.

Comment: I understand the reason you explain me. But I still can't make it work. I will port the idea of this code into a class and I was thinking about to use a method to start the thread in a general way to fit every thread. Also, I may need to interrupt some thread and searching about all the risks about terminating a thread, I decided to make a kind of a flag to force a return (something like I did in the FooTimer example). [continue]

Comment: [...] Do you have any suggestion on how I could make a generic method to start and stop (in one or two method, whatever) the thread passing the name of the function I will use to start thread and a way to "stop it"? A unique global flag could interrupt all the threads together.....creating a lot of flags to each thread is something difficult also since I could start the same function to run in two threads. So, ideas? Again, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As others have already noted, you cannot do this directly.

First of all I would use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of a raw function pointer and [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) to hold the function's name.

I would also wrap these up like this:

```
template<class T>
struct Functor
{
    std::function<T> functor_;
    std::string name_;

    Functor(const std::function<T>& functor, const std::string& name)
        : functor_(functor)
        , name_(name)
    {}
};
```

You can then use it like so:

```
void Bar()
{
    // do something
}

void Foo(const Functor<void()>& functor)
{
}

int main() 
{
    Functor<void()> f(std::bind(Bar), "Bar");
    Foo(f);
    return 0;
}
```

You can also use a macro to make things easier for you.

```
#define FUNCTOR(t, x, ...) Functor<t>(std::bind(&x, __VA_ARGS__), #x)
```

Which can be used like this:

```
int main() 
{
    auto f = FUNCTOR(void(), Bar);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that if you take this approach that the function name might not be the same as what using `__FUNCTION__` yields.